# Sprawling building

Tags: american-english

What are the qualities ascribed to a building someone calls 'sprawling' in American English?  Is it neutral, negative? Does it depend on the context?

Comment: After looking up *sprawl/ing* in the dictionary what questions do you have on how to apply that to a building?

Comment: "to spread or develop in an uneven or uncontrolled way" is a definition I found in a dictionary. But that doesn't give me an idea what kind of building an native speaker imagines exactly when they hear "sprawling building".

Comment: picture a spider… legs everywhere. Look at a google earth plan of the building in question.. similarity?

Comment: Here's an image of what I think of when I hear a *sprawling building*: http://masonholden.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/nissan_factory-2.jpg

Comment: Thanks, Jim. Does the expression have any negative connotations, maybe very subtle ones?

Comment: Here's another: http://www.mccormick.northwestern.edu/about/history.html

Comment: Depending on context, it could actually be almost praise for the structure - but you'd have to be describing a sprawling palace, not an industrial complex

Comment: other end of the scale, architecturally - https://www.google.com/search?q=sprawling+palace&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=SUSLVJvHKoLuUJzJgqAP&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1145&bih=969

Comment: I have made my question more specific. If you say a private person or a family lives in a sprawling house, would that also be praise for the structure?

Comment: No, on it's own it does not have any negative connotations.  It takes context for that.  Here sprawling is a good thing:  "Hey, let's go hide in the Nissan factory.  It sprawls all over, they'll never find us!"  Here it's bad: "Make sure you get to the Nissan plant early, it's such a sprawling monstrosity even if you're on time in the parking lot, you could be 30 mins late getting to the factory floor."

Comment: In itself, it is neither positive nor negative. It really only says it 'takes up a lot of land area' [Edit] It is also the architectural opposite of perhaps 'monolithic' which would imply a single, gigantic structure over a relatively small land area.

Comment: 'huge' is 'volume' not 'area'

Comment: It would essentially be a commentary on their wealth and circumstance.  Whether their wealth and circumstance is viewed as a good thing or a bad thing depends on context.

Comment: The Empire State Building & the Palace of Versailles are 'huge' - only one is 'sprawling'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When used of a single building or non-residential building complex, "sprawling" has a neutral or slightly positive connotation of "I envy how they've grown so quickly", or "they have so much to do, they need that much space to do it in."

When used of a city or residential area, "sprawling" has the negative connotations of "urban sprawl".  Many people who use the term "urban sprawl" resent:

- how spreading cities destroy forests, farmland, and other ecologies;
- how "suburban" car-centric societies allocate half of the land and a quarter of the buildings for use of cars;
- that about half of the population cannot drive (either due to youth, age, disability, or inability to afford a car);
- that pedestrians are subject to a *de facto* death penalty for darting in front of moving cars;
- that sprawling cities mean long commutes, and people spending more time away from their families;
- how many cities pollute(d) their environments, (especially before the implementation of smokestack filters, tailpipe scrubbers, natural gas heat, and sewage treatment plants).

As you can see, these are some strongly negative connotations.

Comment: +1 for a great synopsis of _urban sprawl_. Just one quice note of clarification for the learner: one sprawling building doesn't make urban sprawl. So _sprawl_ applied to one building is often neutral, but _sprawl_ applied to an entire suburb is often tinted negatively.

Answer (score 4):

Sprawling is a sense of 'area covered' in seemingly haphazard manner.

Think of a spider - it sprawls over more area that its volume would suggest

[image]

A building can sprawl in the same way, neither 'good' nor 'bad'
[left is the Palace of Versailles, right is a Nissan car plant]

[image: Palace of Versailles]
[image: Nissan factory]

It doesn't even have to be just a single building, a housing estate can sprawl too
[image]

This is not to be confused with simply being 'massive', 'monolithic', 'huge', 'enormous' [& please, whatever you do don't use 'enormity' as a synonym for merely very large]

The Empire State Building is all about size, but it doesn't sprawl at all…

[image]