# What does "sprawling city" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does ***"sprawling city"*** mean exactly?

I consulted a dictionary and it said that

> **sprawling city** - a city spreading out wide area in a way that is not
>   carefully planned.

But could you please open it up?

Comment: Sprawling cities often have low population density and short buildings.

Comment: The connotations of "urban sprawl" and "sprawling buildings" have been discussed in the answers to [another question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42876).

Comment: The dictionary probably says "spreading out **over** a wide area..."

Answer (score 4):

The adjective  ***[sprawling](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sprawling)*** is used in the expression "sprawling city"  because it conveys the idea  of something that moves or grows over a large  area in a nonordered way:

> - ***The adjective sprawling is good for describing things that extend across a large area.***  You could describe your school as sprawling if it consists of many buildings spread over several acres.
> - ***It's pretty common to hear a city or its suburbs described as sprawling, since some cities tend to grow that way, spreading their populations out over a large amount of land.***  You can also describe your brother as sprawling if he likes to sit stretched out on the couch, taking up more than his share of space.
> - ***The verb sprawl is at the root of sprawling, and it comes from an Old English word, spreawlian, "move convulsively."*** (Vocabulary.com)

***[Sprawl](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sprawl) (n.)***:

> - meaning "straggling expansion of built-up districts into surrounding countryside" is from 1955. (Etymonline)

Note also the expression  ***[urban sprawl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_sprawl):***

> - Urban sprawl or suburban sprawl describes the expansion of human populations away from central urban areas into low-density, monofunctional and usually car-dependent communities, in a process called suburbanization. In addition to describing a particular form of urbanization, the term also relates to the social and environmental consequences associated with this development. (Wikipedia)

Comment: +1. By the Middle English period the meaning had broadened from "to move as in death throes" to "to move one's outspread limbs in a manner lacking purpose and direction (e.g. as a baby does), or to loll about. Wikipedia's "monofunctional" is an exaggeration. Suburbs have their problems, but they do serve more than one function.

Comment: The quoted text for *urban sprawl* does not appear at the link provided. But the quoted text is misleading, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Even though

> sprawl

has a defined meaning, and

> urban sprawl

has [defined ways of being measured](http://www.smartgrowthamerica.org/documents/measuring-sprawl-2014.pdf), what is often meant by a "sprawling city" is a city which extends or over a large area, usually to the horizon, and is usually viewed from a high vantage point so one may see the "sprawl".

[Los Angeles - which might not be considered "sprawling" by some metrics](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andrewbender/2014/04/14/study-reveals-americas-most-sprawling-cities-and-l-a-isnt-one-of-them/#76768d246165)

[image: here]



[The urban sprawl of New Dehli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7IfUU8pWOA)

[here http://indiatransportportal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/new-delhi-10.jpg](http://indiatransportportal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/new-delhi-10.jpg)



[The Sprawling Metropolis of Baltic, SD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1a5prhBxDfA) (a bit tongue in cheek)

[image: here]